# Android Phonegap getting Unfortunately XXX has stopped

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, command-line-interface

I am using phonegap `6.3.0` and I just can't work out what is killing my app. It must be my code as if I create a new project there is no problem.

Below is logcat, looking through it I can't see anything obviously breaking.

I am installing on android. I have had this app work previously, for about 6 months actually. Only recently have I been getting this problem.

I have actually taken a new config.xml and replace my sections where necessary.

```
F/chromium(13288): [FATAL:jni_android.cc(271)] Check failed: false.
F/libc    (13288): Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 13385 (Thread-699)
D/MediaResourceGetter(13288): resource doesn't have video
D/MediaResourceGetter(13288): extracted valid metadata: MediaMetadata[durationInMilliseconds=7667, width=0, height=0, success=true]
D/MediaResourceGetter(13288): resource doesn't have video
D/MediaResourceGetter(13288): extracted valid metadata: MediaMetadata[durationInMilliseconds=15333, width=0, height=0, success=true]
D/MediaResourceGetter(13288): resource doesn't have video
D/MediaResourceGetter(13288): extracted valid metadata: MediaMetadata[durationInMilliseconds=15400, width=0, height=0, success=true]
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): Build fingerprint: 'google/hammerhead/hammerhead:5.0.1/LRX22C/1602158:user/release-keys'
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): Revision: '11'
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): ABI: 'arm'
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): pid: 13288, tid: 13385, name: Thread-699  >>> com.dotb <<<
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): Abort message: '[FATAL:jni_android.cc(271)] Check failed: false.
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): '
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     r0 00000000  r1 00003449  r2 00000006  r3 00000000
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     r4 9c6ffdb8  r5 00000006  r6 00000058  r7 0000010c
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     r8 9c6ffa40  r9 b6ef7df4  sl 00000000  fp 9c6ff9fc
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     ip 00003449  sp 9c6ff518  lr b6ea1af9  pc b6ec4e24  cpsr 600e0010
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): backtrace:
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #00 pc 00039e24  /system/lib/libc.so (tgkill+12)
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #01 pc 00016af5  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_kill+52)
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #02 pc 00017707  /system/lib/libc.so (raise+10)
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #03 pc 00013f75  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_android_abort+36)
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #04 pc 00012a3c  /system/lib/libc.so (abort+4)
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #05 pc 0020cf21  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #06 pc 001f4f1f  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #07 pc 001e6a29  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #08 pc 00410cff  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #09 pc 004102d5  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #10 pc 002040b9  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #11 pc 002042fd  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #12 pc 0020458d  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #13 pc 002023cb  /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #14 pc 000162e3  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+30)
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):     #15 pc 000142d3  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
W/debuggerd( 1483): type=1400 audit(0.0:34): avc: denied { read } for name="kgsl-3d0" dev="tmpfs" ino=6019 scontext=u:r:debuggerd:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:gpu_device:s0 tclass=chr_file
I/DEBUG   ( 1483):
I/DEBUG   ( 1483): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_09
W/ActivityManager( 1946):   Force finishing activity com.dotb/.MainActivity
I/Choreographer(13288): Skipped 70 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
W/InputDispatcher( 1946): channel '23239537 com.dotb/com.dotb.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher( 1946): channel '23239537 com.dotb/com.dotb.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
W/InputDispatcher( 1946): channel '34124dd3 com.dotb/com.dotb.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
E/InputDispatcher( 1946): channel '34124dd3 com.dotb/com.dotb.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
I/WindowState( 1946): WIN DEATH: Window{23239537 u0 com.dotb/com.dotb.MainActivity}
W/InputDispatcher( 1946): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '23239537 com.dotb/com.dotb.MainActivity (server)'
I/WindowState( 1946): WIN DEATH: Window{34124dd3 u0 com.dotb/com.dotb.MainActivity}
W/InputDispatcher( 1946): Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '34124dd3 com.dotb/com.dotb.MainActivity (server)'
W/ActivityManager( 1946): Exception thrown during pause
W/ActivityManager( 1946): android.os.DeadObjectException
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Binder.java:496)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy.schedulePauseActivity(ApplicationThreadNative.java:701)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startPausingLocked(ActivityStack.java:852)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2754)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:2611)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityStackSupervisor.finishTopRunningActivityLocked(ActivityStackSupervisor.java:2453)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleAppCrashLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11568)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.makeAppCrashingLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:11440)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.crashApplication(ActivityManagerService.java:12144)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleApplicationCrashInner(ActivityManagerService.java:11660)
W/ActivityManager( 1946):       at com.android.server.am.NativeCrashListener$NativeCrashReporter.run(NativeCrashListener.java:86)
E/lowmemorykiller(  164): Error writing /proc/13288/oom_score_adj; errno=22
I/Zygote  ( 1498): Process 13288 exited due to signal (6)
I/ActivityManager( 1946): Process com.dotb (pid 13288) has died
I/Adreno-EGL( 1946): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: QUALCOMM Build: 10/24/14, 167c270, I68fa98814b
I/OpenGLRenderer( 1946): Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W/EntryProvider( 2590): Network not available. Skipping invalidate.
W/EntryValidationState( 2590): Network not available. Skipping invalidate.
I/ThermalEngine( 1497): TM Id 'battery_LCD_monitor' Sensor 'batt_therm' - alarm raised 3 at 350.0 degC
E/ThermalEngine( 1497): override action 5000
E/ThermalEngine( 1497): Thermal-Server: Thermal received msg override 5000
E/ThermalEngine( 1497): override_notify : SS mode 1 override 5000
D/audio_hw_primary( 1486): disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: low-latency-playback
D/audio_hw_primary( 1486): disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
D/TaskPersister( 1946): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=13797_task.xml
D/TaskPersister( 1946): removeObsoleteFile: deleting file=13797_task_thumbnail.png
D/WifiService( 1946): acquireWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@2b9beda3}
I/wpa_supplicant( 2085): wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED
D/WifiService( 1946): releaseWifiLockLocked: WifiLock{NlpWifiLock type=2 binder=android.os.BinderProxy@2b9beda3}
I/com.newrelic.agent.android( 5380): Harvester: connected
I/com.newrelic.agent.android( 5380): Harvester: Sending 1 HTTP transactions.
I/com.newrelic.agent.android( 5380): Harvester: Sending 0 HTTP errors.
I/com.newrelic.agent.android( 5380): Harvester: Sending 0 activity traces.
I/com.newrelic.agent.android( 5380): Harvester: Sending 0 analytics events.
E/com.newrelic.agent.android( 5380): Failed to send POST to collector: Unable to resolve host "mobile-collector.newrelic.com": No address associated with hostname
E/com.newrelic.agent.android( 5380): HarvestConnection: Attempting to convert network exception java.net.UnknownHostException to error code.
D/AbstractMetricsFactoryImpl( 5867): Setting non-anonymous customer ID and session ID to null, and anonymous tag to true as the metric entry was not recorded in non-anonymous queue.
```